# How to combine the output of two awk commands into one tab-separated file?

Tags: awk

This is what my file looks like:

```
$ head file.txt
100 495.03
101 503.76
102 512.28
103 520.75
104 529.17
105 537.37
106 545.4
107 553.33
108 561.19
109 568.92
```

I would like to print every 5th line from the first field **and** the average of the average of the first 5 lines and do that for the rest of the file (print 10th line from first field and the average of 5-10 from the second field).

The output should be:

```
104 512.198
109 728.352
```

This works:

```
awk 'NR % 7 == 0 {print $2; next} {sum+=$1} NR%5==0 {print sum/5; sum=0}'
```

but prints the result on new line; I'd like them to be printed in two different fields, space or tab-separated, in one file!

I tried specifying `BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }` at the beginning, but without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure why you are putting `FNR%7==0` as it will check lines like 7,14,21 and so on. But in your post you saying you need only every 5th line, could you please explain(if I have not missed anything here).

Comment: My bad, it's supposed to be `FNR%5==0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '{sum+=$2;count++} FNR%5==0{print $1,(sum/count);count=sum=""}' Input_file
```

Comment: Yup, just wasn't quick enough (was doing some tests with other answers). Thanks!

Comment: @ThePresident, sure, not an issue, keep learning and keep sharing knowledge, cheers.